# PHP: ArrayObject::append() apparently doesn't work in multiple inheritance

Tags: php

I've spent over an hour trying to resolve this issue.

The [documentation page for `ArrayObject::append()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php) contains the following cryptic statement: *This method cannot be called when the ArrayObject was constructed from an object.*  I also tried using `offsetSet(null,...)` as suggested by the note. This isn't working either.

The idea that methods like this don't work if you extend the class multiple times is ludicrous, but that seems to be what's happening here.

**Declarations**

```
abstract class ArrayBase extends \ArrayObject
{
  ....
}

class SpecializedArray extends ArrayBase
{
  ....
}
```

**Test methods**

```
public function testAppend()
{
    $o = new SpecializedArray();
    $o->append('alpha');
    $this->assertEquals(array('alpha'), $o->getArrayCopy());
}

public function testAppendSubstitute()
{
    $o = new SpecializedArray();
    $o->offsetSet(null,'alpha');
    $this->assertEquals(array('alpha'), $o->getArrayCopy());
}

// This one passes.
public function testOffsetSet()
{
    $o = new SpecializedArray();
    $o->offsetSet('blah','alpha');
    $this->assertEquals(array('blah' => 'alpha'), $o->getArrayCopy());
}
```

**Test output**

```
1) testAppend
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => 'alpha'
 )

2) testAppendSubstitute
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => 'alpha'
 )
```

Comment: Did you override `append()` in either implementation? I can't seem to reproduce the issue. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/35VOJ)

Comment: No, I did not override `append()` in either implementation.

Comment: Can you paste `SpecializedArray` and `ArrayBase` in your question?

Comment: Unfiortunately I can't. `ArrayBase` adds a lot of functionality to `ArrayObject`, and `SpecializedClass` is a proxy for at least three different classes that demonstrate the same problem (none of which implement `append()`).

Comment: I see. How about, just to try, remove ALL the code from both classes and test again? `var_dump()` and all.

Comment: Just tried that and the test now works. So I'll take it from there. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome :). Good luck. Be sure to post the solution as an answer when you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your problem. Maybe you implemented wrong `append` or something?

For my test code, it works:

```
<?php

abstract class ArrayBase extends \ArrayObject
{

}

class SpecializedArray extends ArrayBase
{
}

$a = new SpecializedArray();
$a->append('xxx');

var_dump($a->getArrayCopy());
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "xxx"
}
```

Comment: `ArrayBase` doesn't override `append()`. I also added a `var_dump` to my own script and the array is clearly empty even after the `append()`.